# Returning a result when sql query finds no matches

Tags: sql

I am pulling a userid from a database named people and have given it a variable of $userid. That same userid is associated with another table named info, sometimes. Sometimes there is a matching userid, sometimes that userid is not associated with the info table.  When I do the following query, the function is skipped when the userid in the people table does not have a matching userid in the info table. Is there a way to get a result back when no match is found?

```
$club_query = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT clubs FROM info WHERE userid = '$userid' LIMIT 1") );
```

If the club is in the results, then perform a function.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few dirty hacks I've used for this sort of thing. One is to use `MIN(clubs)` instead of `clubs`, since if there are no rows, then `MIN(...)` returns `NULL`:

```
SELECT MIN(clubs) clubs FROM info WHERE userid = ...
```

Another is to use a `RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1) t`:

```
SELECT info.clubs FROM info RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1) t ON info.userid = ...
```

Both approaches work, but have some drawbacks/limitations.

**Edited to add:** another approach that just occurred to me right now is to use a subquery in the field-list:

```
SELECT (SELECT clubs FROM info WHERE userid = ...) clubs;
```

which also converts an empty result-set into `NULL`. This, too, has some limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mentioning null made me wonder if the query as it returns a result of null, and it does. So everything is working great now. Thanks a lot.