# Checking IF IS NULL or IF NOT EXIST, causing SQL Syntax errors

Tags: mysql

The result variable is a hacky way to return a null that I read about. However, the following does not work. Earlier I tried `IF NOT EXIST then '(SELECT min(classID) FROM Classes WHERE title LIKE CoName)'` to no avail either.

Problem Code:

```
Set result = (SELECT min(classID) FROM Classes WHERE title LIKE CoName);
IF result is null THEN
    INSERT INTO Classes (title)
    VALUES (CoName);
END IF;
```

This comes from a stored procedure to populate a new table from an old table. The if statement is to check if the new value has already been added to the new table. The rest of the procedure works without the if statement but gives duplicate entries.

Comment: This is where the hacky idea comes from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745870/returning-a-result-when-sql-query-finds-no-matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to ignore an error on insert, then create a unique index on `CoName`:

```
create unique index classes_coname on classes(coname);
```

Then ignore errors when you insert.  The following ignores all errors:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Classes(title)
    VALUES (CoName);
```

The following is more specific for duplicate key errors:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Classes(title)
    VALUES (CoName)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = CoName;
```